# Convert CGColor to corresponding UIColor in Swift

Tags: swift, uicolor, cgcolor

I am using a light blue `CGColor` and now I want to use this exact color as the background of a `UIButton`.

How can I convert the `CGColor` to `UIColor`?

Answer (score 69):

Get the UIColor from the CGColor using UIColor(cgColor: ...):

```
let uiColor = UIColor(cgColor: cgColor)
```

then assign it as a background color to your button.